# Python doesnt import module from the same folder it imports another

Tags: python

So I have a project like this

```
root/
  api/
  nest/
    nest.py
    tests.py
    __init__.py
```

when I run `python nest/nest.py -args` it works fine, but when I run python nest/tests.py it crashes saying i have an import error in tests.py
 `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nest.nest'; 'nest' is not a package`

my tests.py import looks like this

```
import unittest
from nest.nest import JsonParser
```

I also use this JsonParser class in api/api.py module and it works fine
To add to that, if i run tests.py in pycharm it works normally, but if I try in console, it throws this exception

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your interprerter doesn't know the path in which that module is when running outside the module scope.

A solution could be to add the absolute path of your module in the code:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('my/path/to/module/folder')

import module-of-interest
```

Comment: oh man, you sort of reminded me of a solution i used to do long ago

import sys
sys.path.insert(0,'./')

import module-of-interest

Comment: Hehehe Hope that this helped you @nexla :)